# there exists no bijective map $f :$ $\mathbb R^{2} \to R^{3}$ such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Show that there exists no bijective map $f :$ $\mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R^{3}$ such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable.

I think if there is a bijective map between $\mathbb R^{2}$ and $\mathbb R^{3}$ then $\mathbb R^{2}$ and $\mathbb R^{3}$ will be homeomorphic and it creates a contradiction because they are not homeomorphic.hence there doesn't exist such bijection.

Is it right?If it is right is there any other way to do this using multivariate calculus and not using Topology.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the spaces are not homeomorphic, but that's a very hard theorem to prove. Instead, here's a hint for how to use calculus to aolve the problem: since $f$ and its inverse are differentiable, try applying the chain rule to $f\circ f^{-1}=I$. Now to conclude, use some linear algebra.

Comment: If $f^{-1}$ is differentiable then $[f^{-1}(x)]'$ will be $[f'(x)]^{-1}$ but $f'(x)$ is a 2×3 matrix

Comment: Is it okay ?or please give me some more hint.

Comment: @LAMDA your idea is correct, a 2x3 matrix cannot be invertible. However the point of evaluation of the derivatives is wrong. Apply the chain rule carefully.

Comment: $f o f^{-1}(x)$=$f'(f^{-1}(x))$ o $[f^{-1}(x)]'$ .Now the map in the right side is from $\mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R^{2}$ but in the left side it is from $\mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R^{3}$.which creates a contradiction.     Form chain rule

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: @LAMDA No, now your derivative calculation is correct, but your conclusion is wrong. Both sides are from R3 to R3. The key is that f' (at appropriate point) is from R2 to R3 hence not invertible. But by that equation, it is invertible hence contradiction.